# How to apply countvectorizer to bigrams in a pandas dataframe

Tags: nltk, n-gram, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

I'm trying to apply the ***countvectorizer*** to a dataframe containing bigrams to convert it into a frequency matrix showing the number of times each bigram appears in each row but I keep getting error messages.

This is what I tried using

```
cereal['bigrams'].head()

0    [(best, thing), (thing, I), (I, have),....
1    [(eat, it), (it, every), (every, morning),...
2    [(every, morning), (morning, my), (my, brother),...
3    [(I, have), (five, cartons), (cartons, lying),...
.........
```

```
bow = CountVectorizer(max_features=5000, ngram_range=(2,2))
train_bow = bow.fit_transform(cereal['bigrams'])
train_bow

Expected results


      (best,thing) (thing, I) (I, have)  (eat,it) (every,morning)....
0           1          1          1         0           0
1           0          0          0         1           1
2           0          0          0         0           1
3           0          0          1         0           0
....
```

Comment: thats a good example of the kind of data you have, and what you expect as a result - but it would be even better if you also included the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to convert a pd.Series into a count representation of each term.

Thats a bit different from what CountVectorizer does;

From the function description:

> Convert a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts

The official example of case use is:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())  
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

So, as one can see, it takes as input a list where each term is a "document".
Thats problaby the cause of the errors you are getting, you see, you are passing a pd.Series where each term is a list of tuples.

For you to use CountVectorizer you would have to transform your input into the proper format.

If you have the original corpus/text you can easily implement CountVectorizer on top of it (with the ngram parameter) to get the desired result.

Else, best solution wld be to treat it as it is, a series with a list of items, which must be counted/pivoted.

Sample workaround:

[image]

(it wld be a lot easier if you just use the text corpus instead)

Hope it helps!